# What is the best solution with high accuracy for location based mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, gps, android-gps

I need to implement an app that is need to watch location updates.
I have to solutions in my options:

1. use native app with java and access the GPS data
2. use JavaScript with location services to get location data

I'm not sure witch one is more reliable and precise.

P.S: I need the location data in each ***10 sec***.

Answer (score 0):

In Android you can call function onLocationChanged more here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html Then build timer. Also instead of GPS you can use NETWORK_PROVIDER you will get location too but less accurate

Comment: is it faster that JavaScript solution ? or is it more accrue ?

Comment: I'm thinking that most accure method is by using GPS